# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string when inserting data to multiple table at a time in laravel 5.5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
$user_id   = $request->get('user_id');
            $email     = $request->get('email');
            $course_id = $request->get('course_id');

            $received_by = DB::table('affiliate_users')
                            ->select('first_upline_id','second_upline_id','third_upline_id')
                            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                            ->first();
          // dd($received_by);

           $a = DB::table('affiliate_income')->insert(
                       ['sent_by' => $user_id, 'course_id' => $course_id, 'received_by' => $received_by, ]
                );

           dd($a);
```

I want to insert data to multiple tables at a time. This is my controller's code. $received_by giving me selected values, without $received_by my $a is fine, but when using $received_by, I am getting this error.It should insert data to 'affiliate_users' three rows within same user_id.What should be the right query.Please someone help me. Here is my table bellow-
[image: affiliate_income]

Comment: you want received_by equals to 'first_upline_id','second_upline_id' or 'third_upline_id'? you only select these 3 column, and if you want access it, use $received_by->first_upline_id

Comment: `$received_by` is not a string

Comment: I think you mean this `'received_by' => $received_by->name` or id ??

Comment: Then, should i write ['sent_by' => $user_id, 'course_id' => $course_id, 'received_by' => $received_by->first_upline_id, 'received_by' => $received_by->second_upline_id, 'received_by' => $received_by->third_upline_id, ]

Comment: Did you setting the structure of  your column user_id as unique?

Comment: for users table user id is unique,when inserting data to above 'affiliate_users', then i am using user_id to sent_by and sent_by is not unique, sent_by should be three rows when insert data one time within the received_by three different id from first_upline_id, second_upline_id and third_upline_id.

Comment: Isn't normal you got float at the end of you array param ['sent_by' => $user_id, 'course_id' => $course_id, 'received_by' => $received_by, ] i guess you don't needed.

Comment: Let me explain more- I have three tables one is 'buy_courses', second one is 'affiliate_incomes' and third one is 'affiliate_users'. I am going to insert data to 'buy_courses' and 'affiliate_incomes' required 'firs_upline_id', second_upline_id'  and 'third_upline_id' as recieved_by from another table 'affiliate_users' for further approach . Then, what should be the right query? please..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a column named as `received_by` in your table and you are here storing `received_by` id then

```
$user_id   = $request->get('user_id');
            $email     = $request->get('email');
            $course_id = $request->get('course_id');

            $received_by = DB::table('affiliate_users')
                            ->select('first_upline_id','second_upline_id','third_upline_id')
                            ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                            ->first();
          // dd($received_by);

           $a = DB::table('affiliate_income')
->insert(['sent_by' => $user_id, 'course_id' => $course_id, 'received_by' => $received_by->received_by
//(or whatever you have to insert from $received_by object), 
                ]);

           dd($a);
```